# conda create R environment

Tags: r, conda, dependency-resolution

How can I create afresh conda environment with R support and RStudio?
The code below fails to work for me:

```
conda create -n datascience-r rstudio
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package r-stringr conflicts for:
rstudio -> r-stringr[version='>=0.6']
Package qt conflicts for:
rstudio -> qt=5.6
Package r-httpuv conflicts for:
rstudio -> r-httpuv[version='>=1.3.3']
Package r-readxl conflicts for:
rstudio -> r-readxl[version='>=0.1.0']
```

Comment: https://alexanderlabwhoi.github.io/post/anaconda-r-sarah/ helps a lot. But still not fully there usng RStudio with conda on Windows.

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show channels`?

Comment: The single corporate Artifactory which has been configured to support R via a CRAN mirror

Comment: Is there any way you will be able to change channels to `defaults` and `conda-forge` and try with them?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.